# How to make SharePoint 2010 Page compatible in IE 6.0?

Tags: ie6

How to make SharePoint 2010 Page compatible in IE 6.0?

Has anyone worked on similar requirement???

Basically what all things to take care?

e.g. Ribbon control

If any one has any reference links/documents, please suggest.

Regards,

Ketan

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer 6.0 is not supported in SharePoint 2010.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you could do, downgrade your site collection (the one hosting the search center) to SharePoint 2007 UI. This one might work with IE. Check [Revert a SharePoint 2010 site to the WSS3.0/MOSS2007 Look after Visual Upgrade](http://dirkvandenberghe.com/archive/2009/12/04/revert-a-sharepoint-2010-site-to-the-wss3-0-moss2007-look-after-visual-upgrade.aspx). I haven't tried to use it with IE6 so you will need to try this on your own.

---

To be honest, the days of IE6 are over. As a responsible consultant you should discuss this with your client or within your organization. It would be much better to upgrade browser to a never version of IE or some other browser than doing these nasty hacks to use SharePoint 2010 with IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Ketan:

The best I can suggest is that you try redirecting requests from IE6.0 to your sites mobile client pages.  You will need to configure your sites to support mobile clients.

Dave,

Answer (score 1):

We've been having the same conversations here, we are moving a site to SP2010 but still need to support some Users with IE6.  It's limited to only Published Pages, so the exposure is limited, although the issues may not be - especially if the cursory testing on our internal site with IE6 is an example of what Users will see there will be lots of "your software is incompatible" popups on many pages.  Some customers may not be able to upgrade browsers, due to internal tools they may need to use, so telling them that they must upgrade is not always an option.  FireFox does seem to run well with SP2010, so if IE6 upgrade is not an option, starting a conversation about multiple browsers may not be.  Otherwise you are stuck with the page compatible options already presented.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your response.

I am aware that IE 6.0 is not supported in Share point 2010, however i have requirement where i want to use only share point 2010 search center and rest of the portal is built on top of MOSS 2007, hence end user will be using IE 6.0.

Thanks,
Ketan

Comment: From what I gather to date, the only aspect at all which may be supported with Internet Explorer 6 are Publishing Pages where the markup has been carefully crafted to ensure compatibility. 

SharePoint 2010 Search would run from a SharePoint 2010 Web Application therefore the base browser requirements are as that of Internet Explorer 6.

Also, Microsoft are phasing out support of IE6 (due to the age of the software and the overall cost of maintenance and compatibility). As such, any planning for any aspect of SP2010 must take browser version into account.